# Is it possible to make rsync make a log-file on a remote system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to connect and back up to a hard drive on a remote computer that I have ssh access to. `rsync` is connecting correctly. The code that's working is

```
rsync -av --progress -e "ssh -p port_number -i key/file/path" \
  "path/on/local/computer/to/back/up" \
  ssh_username@ssh_ip_address:"'path/on/remote/computer/to/back/up/to'"
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get `rsync` to use its `--log-file` option to generate a log-file on the remote system (I want the file to be on the same remote hard drive that I'm backing up to). Any time I give it a remote path to use for the log-file (for example, with `--log-file="path/on/remote/computer"`), it seems to be looking for the path on my local system. I even tried `--log-file=ssh_username@ssh_ip_address:path/on/remote/system`, but it didn't work.

Is this possible, or do I need to make a log-file on the local system and then `scp` it to the remote system?

Both the local and remote systems are running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What OS are you using? It might be relevant.

Comment: @ terdon, ha, I edited my post with that information at the same time as you were commenting. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on both systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the `rsync` to the other machine and then just run a `scp` command after to put the locally generated log file to the remote system where you'd like it kept.

#### rsyncing file + log

```
% rsync -avz -e 'ssh' $HOME/sample.sh remotemach:~ \
                --log-file=$HOME/rsync.log ; scp $HOME/rsync.log remotemach:~
```

#### confirming

```
% ls -l ~/rsync.log ~/sample.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 10059 Oct 15 15:20 /home/saml/sample.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml   192 Feb  2 14:57 /home/saml/rsync.log

% ssh remotemach "ls -l sample.sh rsync.log"
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 10059 Oct 15 15:20 sample.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml   192 Feb  2 14:54 rsync.log
```

### concatating the log to the remote side

If you'd like to concatanate the results from `rsync` to a remote file you can use a compound command ([see bash's man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping)). Here I'm wrapping `rsync` with parens, and piping its output to `ssh` through a pipe, i.e.:

```
(rsync ...) | ssh ...
```

#### 1st file copied

```
% (rsync -avz -e'ssh' $HOME/sample1.sh remotemach:~) \
                    | ssh remotemach "cat >> \$HOME/rsync.log"
```

#### confirm 1st copy

```
% ssh remotemach "ls -l sample*.sh rsync.log"
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml   133 Feb  2 19:49 rsync.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 10059 Feb  2 19:25 sample1.sh
```

#### 2nd file copied

```
% (rsync -avz -e'ssh' $HOME/sample2.sh remotemach:~) \
                    | ssh remotemach "cat >> \$HOME/rsync.log"
```

#### confirm 2nd copy

```
% ssh remotemach "ls -l sample*.sh rsync.log"
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml   266 Feb  2 20:03 rsync.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 10059 Feb  2 19:25 sample1.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 10059 Feb  2 19:25 sample2.sh
```

**NOTE:** Pay special attention to the file on the right side of the `ssh`. Notice that the `$HOME` path has a forward slash () in front of the `$HOME`. This is on purpose. It's necessary to escape the `$HOME` so that the local host's bash shell does not expand it.

Comment: @ slm, that makes sense. Thank you!

What I would like to do is append the log-file to an existing log-file on the remote machine. Can `scp` append rather than overwrite a file?

Comment: Following my question to @ slm above, I realized (following the post at https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/append-file-681666/#post3334120) that something like `cat localfile | ssh user@remoteserver "cat >> remotefile"` might work.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include a concatenation example as well.

Comment: The compound command method gives you a way to accomplish what you were originally asking too. I didn't think of it until after.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to necro the 9 year old post, but it's the first google result for "rsync log file remote"

I was looking through the man pages today and it appears the `--remote-option` flag is what we're looking for here.  Not sure if this option existed in 2013, but here in 2022 it does!

Apparently by chaining this `--remote-option` with `--log-file` you can generate a log on the remote machine, even for a non-daemon transfer.

```
 -M, --remote-option=OPTION
              This  option  is  used  for  more advanced situations where you want certain effects to be limited to one side of the
              transfer only.  For instance, if you want to pass --log-file=FILE and --fake-super to the remote system,  specify  it
              like this:

              rsync -av -M --log-file=foo -M--fake-super src/ dest/
```

It's also mentioned in the --log-file section

```
--log-file=FILE
              This  option  causes rsync to log what it is doing to a file.  This is similar to the logging that a daemon does, but
              can be requested for the client side and/or the server side of a non-daemon transfer.  If specified as a  client  op‐
              tion,  transfer  logging will be enabled with a default format of "%i %n%L".  See the --log-file-format option if you
              wish to override this.

              Here’s a example command that requests the remote side to log what is happening:

                rsync -av --remote-option=--log-file=/tmp/rlog src/ dest/

              This is very useful if you need to debug why a connection is closing unexpectedly.
```

Personally I'm still having issues with rsync complaining that the logfile doesn't exist. But I think I'm on the right track with this approach.