# How to log the output from an rsync backup which runs from a script using crontab?

Tags: linux, rsync, cron, bash-scripting, crontab

I would like to log all the output that is generated by rsync; the output that I see when I run the script myself in terminal. I would prefer this logging to occur from within my script.

Here is my backup script, it works fine. BackupPC.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#current date and time to be used as filename
CDT=`date +%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M`

echo "[START]  $(date)" >> /home/pi/logs/${CDT}.txt
rsync "-avXP" "bassam@192.168.1.2:/home/bassam/Desktop" "/media/hitachi/backup"
echo "[END]  $(date)" >> /home/pi/logs/${CDT}.txt
```

Here is my crontab entry:

```
0 2 * * * ~/scripts/BackupPC.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bassam:

The rsync command has the --log-file option. In the manual entry:

```
$ -> man -P cat rsync | grep 'log-file=FILE'
            --log-file=FILE         log what we're doing to the specified FILE
```

Then, if I wanna move the file from source/Example to destination and dump the result in the result file, e,g:

```
rsync -avz source/Example destination/ --log-file=result
```

The result is:

```
)$ -> cat result 
2020/06/11 22:09:04 [13891] building file list
2020/06/11 22:09:04 [13891] >f+++++++++ Example
2020/06/11 22:09:04 [13891] sent 101 bytes  received 35 bytes  272.00 bytes/sec
2020/06/11 22:09:04 [13891] total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Or you can use "--log-file=filename -q" It has more information:

```
cat result 
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] building file list
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] [sender] make_file(Example,*,0)
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] send_file_list done
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] send_files starting
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] send_files phase=1
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] send_files phase=2
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] send files finished
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] sent 61 bytes  received 12 bytes  146.00 bytes/sec
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
2020/06/11 22:20:47 [16240] [sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1196): about to call exit(0)
```

Edit:

This could also be helpful: [Is it possible to make rsync make a log-file on a remote system?](https://superuser.com/questions/545642/is-it-possible-to-make-rsync-make-a-log-file-on-a-remote-system)

You have another information that can be helpful in your log file:

```
$ -> rsync --info=help
Use OPT or OPT1 for level 1 output, OPT2 for level 2, etc.; OPT0 silences.

BACKUP     Mention files backed up
COPY       Mention files copied locally on the receiving side
DEL        Mention deletions on the receiving side
FLIST      Mention file-list receiving/sending (levels 1-2)
MISC       Mention miscellaneous information (levels 1-2)
MOUNT      Mention mounts that were found or skipped
NAME       Mention 1) updated file/dir names, 2) unchanged names
PROGRESS   Mention 1) per-file progress or 2) total transfer progress
REMOVE     Mention files removed on the sending side
SKIP       Mention files that are skipped due to options used
STATS      Mention statistics at end of run (levels 1-3)
SYMSAFE    Mention symlinks that are unsafe

ALL        Set all --info options (e.g. all4)
NONE       Silence all --info options (same as all0)
HELP       Output this help message

Options added for each increase in verbose level:
1) COPY,DEL,FLIST,MISC,NAME,STATS,SYMSAFE
2) BACKUP,MISC2,MOUNT,NAME2,REMOVE,SKIP
```

Comment: I added "--log-file=/home/pi/logs/${CDT}.txt" to the script and it worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Perfect Bassam. You could validate the answer if it has been useful to you and welcome to Superuser. Regards.